# How can we take use Cholesky factorization to show that a given symmetric matrix, M is positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, cholesky-decomposition

Let's discard the fact that we know anything about the eigenvalues of being real and positive. Can we still prove a symmetric matrix to be semi-definite? What should be its properties?
I have a matrix, M of the form M[i,j] = 1/n*$\sum_{k=1}^n x[k+i]x[k+j]$,
how can I prove this to be a PSD?

Comment: I dont understand the question. Not all symmetric matrices are PSD, so you cant conclude anything about a matrix being PSD solely from the fact that it is symmetric.

Comment: How do I prove the matrix to be PSD without using the knowledge about its eigenvalues?

Comment: You have to show that $x^\intercal M x \geq 0$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Sure, but how do I show this? Any help?